# How do I completely uninstall everything install by npm (i.e. how do I ensure a fresh install of npm installed)?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm having some version issues with Angular, ng, etc.  I'd like to start from the beginning and uninstall everything that has been installed and start over. I'm on Windows.

I found some information here: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html

I ran this from a cmd line and it didn't seem to do anything:
npm uninstall npm -g

I reran as admin and it deleted some of the things I installed but not everything.

This is from cmd with out admin:

```
C:\>npm uninstall npm -g
up to date in 0.12s

C:\>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 12.16.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.1
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.1
@schematics/angular               9.1.1
@schematics/update                0.901.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

This is what is left after running as admin:

```
c:\>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 12.16.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.1
@schematics/angular          9.1.1
@schematics/update           0.901.1
rxjs                         6.5.4


c:\>
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is I'm not understanding the difference between global installs and installs that are specific to my current project.  I'm starting to dig into this: https://docs.npmjs.com/.  Are there other references I can look at that will explain in detail what each command does?

Comment: anything you added with a -g will be global. they are generally needed to quick start stuff directly like create-react-app for example. dependencies in your package.json are specific to your project and devDependencies are what are only available in dev mode and will not be installed in production. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-documentation/cli these are all the commands in a nutshell.

Answer (score 3):

These commands in the package.json file could come in handy. You could also just delete the node_modules folder manually, adjust your dependencies in package.json and reinstall.

```
"build": "npm build",
"clean": "rm -rf node_modules", 
"reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install", 
"rebuild": "npm run clean && npm install && npm run build",
```

Edit: i forgot to put in the command for clean in windows its:
`"clean":"rmdir /s /q node_modules"`

Also if your issue is with the global angular/cli package you could:
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli` to uninstall the angular/cli.
`npm cache clean` to clean your npm cache from app data folder under your username.
use `npm cache verify` to verify your cache whether it is corrupted or not.
use `npm cache verify --force` to clean your entire cache from your system.

Note:
You can also delete by the following the paths
C:\Users\"Your_syste_User_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm and
C:\Users\"Your_syste_User_name"\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
Then use the following command to install latest angular/cli version globally in your system.
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issue with angular/cli then use the following commands:
npm uninstall -g angular-cli to uninstall the angular/cli.
npm cache clean to clean your npm cache from app data folder under your username.
use npm cache verify to verify your cache whether it is corrupted or not.
use npm cache verify --force to clean your entire cache from your system.

Note:  try using -f or -force flag if the above commmands are not working .